# Selenium Protractor in Javascript: Extracting getText keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

I have an element with inner text on my page I want to extract.

So I do:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="searchQuery"]')).getText().then(function (text){
    return text;
});
```

but I always get an `undefined` return value.

Is there another way of extracting text?

Comment: What if you put `console.log(text);` into the `then()` function - would you see the text value on the console?

Comment: I call console.log from another file and it displays undefined.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Are you sure an element with `id="searchQuery"` has text? Do you know which text (or part of it) should be there in the element? (can help me to provide you with an option)

Comment: The text is between tags <span id="searchQuery"...>inner text is here</span>

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to [*wait for a particular text to be present in element*](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var searchQuery = $('#searchQuery');

var condition = EC.textToBePresentInElement(searchQuery, 'some text');
browser.wait(condition, 10000, "Text is still not present");

searchQuery.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

---

Or, if you don't know what text would be present in the element - just check if any text is there:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var searchQuery = $('#searchQuery');

function waitForText(elementFinder) {
    return function () {
        return elementFinder.getText().then(function(text) {
            return text !== "";  // could also be replaced with "return !!text;"
        });
    };
};

browser.wait(waitForText(searchQuery), 10000, "Text is still not present");

searchQuery.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```